# Tell forEach to wait, and mostly avoid wrapping everything inside an async function to use await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronization

So I got a problem, here is the code:

```
const resultsArray = [];

function parseDoc(doc) {
    const docStringified = JSON.stringify(doc);
    console.log(docStringified);
    docObject = JSON.parse(docStringified);
    resultsArray.push(docObject.name);
};

resultsCollections.forEach(parseDoc);

console.log(resultsArray);
```

I'm using MongoDB, so resultsCollections is a CommandCursor that I put in a forEach to push the results inside the Array so I can use Array.every() to match if a collection already exists and if not it creates one.

Now if you look at the code right now, this is what would happen in the logs:

```
> []
> whatever would come from docstringify
> and if there is a second collection, it would be printed here too, because of forEach
```

Now my problem here is that, if you look at the order of the program, resultsArray is after resultsCollections.forEach(parseDoc) but it prints first.

What I want the log to be is this:

```
> whatever would come from docstringify
> and if there is a second collection, it would be printed here too, because of forEach
> []
```

And that without doing a lot, if possible.

What I know is, thats because forEach... has something async in it and basically it's like this, "If you don't put await inside me, I won't wait".

So I wrapped it inside async and tested it without the console.log inside the async function, which resulted [] still being printed first, because async function is the same problem.

So I am forced to put console.log(resultsArray); inside the async function and call the async function.

Now my problem is, since I have other functions that have to be executed, would be executed to quickly before the async function ends, I have to wrap nearly everything inside an async function and call the other functions to avoid lines being executed after javascript reads like, async and then it continues.

How can I prevent putting and wrapping my entire code inside an async function and use await for everything, and then call the other functions, how can I avoid that?

I've also tried it with a Promise by just using .then after the toArray() because that one can return a promise, but everything that is outside of the promise still gets executed while the promise isn't even finished.

I want to tell forEach, that after it finished execute console.log

What are the possibilities to do this? I try to search all, everything that is possible. Because the current, putting async and call other functions is kinda huh... a lot like when it comes to how the code looks later. But if there is no other possibility, well then I guess I can't decide.

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Cursor.forEach`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Cursor.html#forEach)s second parameter is a function called back after the first callback was executed. Use that to work with the resulting array.

```
 resultsCollections.forEach(parseDoc, function() {
   console.log(resultsArray);
   //...
 });
```

Alternatively you can `await` the returned promise:

```
 (async function() {
    const resultsArray = [];

    function parseDoc(doc) { /*...*/ }

    await resultCollections.forEach(parseDoc);

    console.log(resultsArray);
 })();
```

> How can I prevent putting and wrapping my entire code inside an async function and use await for everything, and then call the other functions, how can I avoid that?

You just have to make the functions `async` that do actually do asynchronous tasks.

Comment: The first code, that I tested like this: https://pastebin.com/h38UrBM7 I've provided also the output in the pastebin. Everything I add after that code will basically get executed instead of waiting for the entire thing. Which is what I tried to prevent, isn't that possible doing that by using not many promises or async? Or let's say I have functions that should wait, then I guess I must callback them using another function that gets called, otherwise it technically like in javascript, it wont work?

Comment: @karl-police yes. You cannot get the newspaper of tomorrow right now. You are asking for something impossible

Comment: Alright, thanks for helping me and letting know. :)

Comment: when does the callback get called though, I know there is error and results parameters and now looking again into it, I actually forgot or I can't see when it gets called, unless it automatically calls when the results are being made, but we're not giving any arguments so I wonder how it works.

Comment: Oh maybe I understand it now again, it gets called after the forEach finished of course, like await probably, but mostly like .then() from the promise and you don't need to give arguments to it unless you want to do something with the error or results, whatever result that would be then...